# org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'

Tags: react-native

I am getting below error when tried to build apk for android in react native. Issue started when I added one of dependencies [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient). Below is the log that I am getting and my gradle.build file. I have tried few things like

1. Matching sdk version with build target version build.gradle file.
2. Lowing gradle version
3. Changing to latest react native version

   - Exception is:
     org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:98)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
         at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
         at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
         at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:230)
         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:227)
         at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:95)
         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
         at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
         at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:185)
         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
         at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:115)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
         at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:90)
         ... 70 more
     Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
         at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:873)
         at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:178)
         ... 82 more
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing '/Users/gautamr/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt' with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/gautamr/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar -M /Users/gautamr/localDev/latest/Lookplex/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/gautamr/localDev/latest/Lookplex/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release -m -J /Users/gautamr/localDev/latest/Lookplex/android/app/build/generated/source/r/release -F /Users/gautamr/localDev/latest/Lookplex/android/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-release.ap_ --custom-package com.lookplex -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/gautamr/localDev/latest/Lookplex/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/release --no-version-vectors}
         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
         at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:871)
         ... 83 more
     Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing '/Users/gautamr/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt' with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/gautamr/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar -M /Users/gautamr/localDev/latest/Lookplex/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/gautamr/localDev/latest/Lookplex/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release -m -J /Users/gautamr/localDev/latest/Lookplex/android/app/build/generated/source/r/release -F /Users/gautamr/localDev/latest/Lookplex/android/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-release.ap_ --custom-package com.lookplex -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/gautamr/localDev/latest/Lookplex/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/release --no-version-vectors}
         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:75)
         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
         at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
         at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
         at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:60)
     Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/gautamr/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
         at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:47)
         ... 9 more

   BUILD FAILED

   Total time: 24.062 secs
   error Command failed with exit code 1.

build.gradle file .............

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    targetSdkVersion = 22
    supportLibVersion = "23.1.0"
}

subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
      afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 23
                buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that I was using png image, which is not supported on android.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android.enableAapt2=false` line to your `gradle.properties`  it should fix your problem.

also ensure on `build.gradle` file in the app you've added the following;

```
compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
```